# Email is shown by the sender email ID instead of receiver

Tags: email

I made archive folder in outlook and shifted my all "sent" emails in that folder.

When I check my sent email in the archive folder, need to find a specific email, all email was shown by the sender email ID instead of the receiver.

This is the main problem to find the receiver email ID in an archive folder.

How I can arrange it by the receiver email ID.

Comment: What version of Outlook is this, and what version of OS X are you running? PLus, can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Saved "Send" messages do not have the "To" (recipient) set as default sorting.

They are set by default to the "From" (you), so that is why you have that sorting.

In order to sort them by the recipient (To) use following:

Arrange by: To:

[image]

Then choose the as Default view for that folder here:

[image]